# How do i make borderless cards without any border in semantic ui

Tags: css, semantic-ui

How do I make the below card borderless with no line border?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div class="ui cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Elliot Fu</div>
      <div class="meta">Friend</div>
      <div class="description">
        Elliot Fu is a film-maker from New York.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `box-shadow` which need to remove.

you have to provide `box-shadow: none;` to this css select `body .ui.cards>.card`.

```css
body .ui.cards>.card{
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div class="ui cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Elliot Fu</div>
      <div class="meta">Friend</div>
      <div class="description">
        Elliot Fu is a film-maker from New York.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not `border` but `box-shadow` add the css in the snippet and it won't display it any more

```css
body .ui.card, body .ui.cards>.card{
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.3/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div class="ui cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Elliot Fu</div>
      <div class="meta">Friend</div>
      <div class="description">
        Elliot Fu is a film-maker from New York.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```